# Drools variable binding: reassignment not allowed

Tags: drools

Assume that `MyObject` is a Java Object with an integer property called `integerProperty`. 
I would like to write a Drools rule like the following (syntactically incorrect):

```
rule "myRule"
    when
        MyObject( $integerProperty : integerProperty )
        accumulate(
            $o : MyObject( 
                integerProperty == $integerProperty + 1,
                $integerProperty : this.integerProperty
                );
            $total : count($o);
            $total > 10
            )
    then 
        [BLABLABLA]
end
```

I want to fire my rule when there is a set of more than 10 elements of type `MyObject` whose `integerProperty` values form an arithmetic sequence, e.g. `1`, `2`, `3`, … In this case, I will assign a negative value to an `HardMediumSoftLongScore` object (hoping that information this helps).

I am sure that an `MyObject` having a given `integerProperty` is unique (eg. there is just one `MyObject` having `integerProperty` equal to, say, `2`). The problem is that I'm not allowed to re-assign the variable binding `$integerProperty`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Can you explain your requirement? As per my understanding, you are accumulating an ordered sequence of objects and want to do something when the accumulator value is greater than 10. Can you give some more details ?

Comment: I tried to edit the question, I hope it helps! Thanks for the interest!

Comment: Do you want to accumulate the object like a rolling group of an object or tumbled grouped ?

Comment: I'm missing something, sorry. Could you explain the difference, please?

Comment: Tumbling means that the number of objects in that window will be grouped and the window will shift based on the window size whereas in case of sliding the window will slide by 1. For example, let's say your window length is 5; In tumbling window the windows object will be o1,o2,o3,o4,o5 in the first window and then second window will have o6,o7,o8,o9,o10 but in case of sliding window the objects inside the first window is o1,o2,o3,o4,o5 and in the second window is o2,o3,o4,o5,o6.

Comment: Then it's definitely sliding.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the below example and check whether you are getting your desired output. Before firing the rule insert the previous object as a global variable (prev in the example below) in the drool session.

```
global MyObject prev;

rule "myRule"
when
  $total : Number(doubleValue > 10) from accumulate(
                        $o : MyObject( prev.getIntegerProperty() != null && $i : integerProperty == prev.getIntegerProperty() + 1),
                      init( double total = 0;),
                      action( total += 1; ),
                      reverse( total -= 1; ),
                      result( new Double( total ) ) )
then
    [BLABLABLA]
end
```

In your java code before firing the rule set the previous object as a global object. Follow the code below :

```
kieSession.setGlobal("prev",myprevobject)
kieSession.insert(myobject)
kieSession.fireAllRules()
```

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit more? Do you mean that there must be a `global MyObject prev` in the `.drl` file? Where in the code above am I setting it to the previous `MyObject` with the desired properties?

Comment: Sorrry, but I'm quite new to Drools.

Comment: Does the above rule fulfills your requirement?

Comment: No, it doesn't fire properly. The rule engine cannot recognize `prev`.